# Number of Lattice paths through some point

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, binomial-coefficients

I have a problem about lattice paths. Here, I mean we can only use (1,0) or (0,1) as steps.

We know the number of lattice paths on an $n\times n$ grid that go through $(i,j)$ is equal to $\binom{i+j}{i}\binom{2n-i-j}{n-i}$. And we denote it by $F(i,j)$.

We know $F(i,j)=F(j,i)=F(n-i,n-j)=F(n-j,n-i)$. My question is that is there any other different point, say $(p,q)$ such that $F(i,j)=F(p,q)$?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not in general.  However, for particular values of $n$, you sometimes get some coincidences.  For example, if $n=7$, $F(1,3)=F(2,4)=840.$  For $n\le 100$, the only values of $n$ for which any value $F(i,j)$ occurs more than four times are
$${7, 15, 17, 19, 27, 31, 32, 34, 38, 47, 49, 55, 59, 71, 76, 77, 79,
87, 97};$$
in none of these cases does any $F(i,j)$ occur more than eight times.